# Converting ZCTA into longitude and latitude

Tags: python, csv, spyder, qgis, geocode

I have a set of ZCTA from census Bureau's website in a csv file. I want to convert this into geographic coordinates to show them on map in QGIS. I know how to convert places name into longitude and latitude using geocode. I was wondering how can I do the same thing using ZCTA. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain Shapefiles for legal boundaries of each year including their ZCTA from [here](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/tiger-line-file.html), then join it with the data you have based on the ZCTA (or manually select a custom subset).